# Unable to create a file inside temp dir - Permission denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, temp

From what I understand on temp file's and directories, the following code should be ok, but I'm getting a permission denied error message.

What I'm trying to do here is download a s3 file and write the contents to another file inside the `TemporaryDirectory`

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(prefix='some_prefix') as temp_dir:
    with open('some_name.csv', 'w+b') as f:
        s3_client.download_fileobj(bucket.name, file_path, f)
        f.seek(0)


Output:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'some_name.csv'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `temp_dir` at all, and as such `'some_name.csv'` refers to your process's working directory. Use e.g. `os.path.join`:

```
with open(os.path.join(temp_dir, 'some_name.csv'), 'w+b') as f:
```

Comment: Omg. Evidence of a long day and I need some rest. Thanks!